# How to Optimize calculation for pandas using computed value for previous row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say we have a dataframe::

```
d = {'date':[01-01-2022,01-02-2022,01-03-2022,01-04-2022], 
      'col1': [1, 2,3,4], 
     'col2': [3, 4,5,6], 
     'a': [4,1,3,1],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

from this data frame I want to calculate col3 which is defined as the following:

```
((Col1 - Sum of col3 for previous dates) / Col2) * a
```

So col 3 in the first row would be:
((1 - 0 [no previous data]) / 3) * 4 = 1.333

col 3 in the 2nd row would be
((2 - 1.33) / 4) * 1 = .1675

col 3 in the 3rd row would be:
((3 - (1.33+.1675) / 5) * 3 = .9015

So the value of col 3 is dependent on all values of column 3 in the rows above it.

Given this situation is there a way to calculate column 3 that does not involves iterating through the data frame rows? Iterating through the rows does not scale well and I need to run a similar calculation for a data frame with 100K rows.

My current approach for this would be the following:

```
df['col3'] = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    sum_previous_rows = df[df['date'] <row['date']]['col3'].sum()
    df[index,'col3'] = ((row['col1'] -sum_previous_rows )/ row['col2']) * row['a']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `[expanding sum]`(https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'date':['01-01-2022','01-02-2022','01-03-2022','01-04-2022'], 
      'col1': [1, 2,3,4], 
     'col2': [3, 4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['col1+2'] = df['col1'] + df['col2']

df['col3'] = df['col1+2'].expanding(1).sum()
```

This will get you this:

| - | date | col1 | col2 | col1+2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01-01-2022 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 4.0 |
| 1 | 01-02-2022 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 10.0 |
| 2 | 01-03-2022 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 18.0 |
| 3 | 01-04-2022 | 4 | 6 | 10 | 28.0 |

Comment: You are correct, but I did simplify my issue for this question. I made an edit to showcase the more complex item I'm working on, where I don't believe expanding sum can be used.

Comment: In your new exammple, I would try with `itertuples` because sometimes it is a bit faster than `iterrows`. But I don't know a way to do it without iterating over rows...